# Does $a = 0$ iff $a \equiv 0 \ (\operatorname{mod} p)$ for every prime $p$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> Suppose $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. Does $a = 0$ iff $a \equiv 0 \ (\operatorname{mod} p)$ for every prime $p$?

It's probably a silly question, but I don't know how to go about it. I'm motivated by the common contest math trick of considering a Diophantine equation $\operatorname{mod} p$. By naturality of $\mathrm{eval}_{x}: (-[t]) \to \mathrm{id}_{\mathbf{CRing}}$ the above question is at least as strong as the following:

> Is an integer a root of a diophantine equation iff it is a root of the said equation mod every prime number?

It's also cool that this question is equivalent to the following:

> Are functions on $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Z}$ completely defined by their values on points of the underlying topological space?

I don't know how to approach this question, but I'd be grateful for an answer or a hint (if it's not much harder than a typical exercise in an abstract algebra textbook).

Comment: If $a\in \mathbb Z \setminus \{0\}$, choose a prime $p$ with $0 < |a| < p$. Then $a \not\equiv 0 \pmod p$.

Comment: @martini Ah, this reminds me of how integers are encoded in computers :) Thank you!

Comment: I guess you really balcked out here - I wonder how one can know what Spec is without noticing martini's observation. :)

Comment: @Hagen I'm weird :D

Comment: Fun, related fact: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number

Comment: This reminds me of an amusing result I saw a number of years ago:
The function$f(x) = (x^2-2)(x^2-3)(x^2-6)$
has a integral root for every prime $p$
(apply quadratic reciprocity and $2*3=6$)
but not over the reals. (Don't know if this should be a comment or answer, so flog me appropriately if I am wrong.)

Comment: By martini's observation, we see that not every sequence of residues comes from an integer. So what is the nature of the ring $\mathbb{F}_2 \times \mathbb{F}_3 \times \mathbb{F}_5 \times \cdots$? Hmmm...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you mentioned $\text{Spec}$, the appropriate generalization to arbitrary commutative rings is the following: an element of a commutative ring $R$ is completely determined by its value mod all prime ideals $P$ if and only if $R$ has trivial [nilradical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilradical_of_a_ring) (hence is a [reduced ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_ring)), and is completely determined by its value mod all maximal ideals $m$ if and only if $R$ has trivial [Jacobson radical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_radical) (hence is a [semiprimitive or Jacobson semisimple ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprimitive_ring)).

An abstract form of the Nullstellensatz asserts that if $R$ is a [Jacobson ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_ring), then any finitely generated $R$-algebra is also a Jacobson ring. In a Jacobson ring, the nilradical and Jacobson radical coincide, so a Jacobson ring is reduced iff it is semiprimitive.